# Received messages are not showing names of contacts on HTC Desire S

Tags: contacts, htc-desire, 2.3-gingerbread, sms

I just bought a new HTC Desire S (so no custom ROM has been installed or rooting done). Everything else seems to be working fine, except in messages the names of at least one contact are not displayed. This number happens to be in my contact list with the proper details and linked with a facebook contact. Even after copy-pasting the number from the received message onto the contact (which has only one number btw), the messages app refuses to show the name. What should I do?

Comment: Can you post the phone number (with last digits replaced with xxxx) exactly as it appears in the phone book and inte messages app?

Answer (score 1):

http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-inspire-4g/110483-phone-number-instead-contact-name.html

HTC is aware of the issue but there is *no* true fix for it yet. Anything in that link is temporary, but it's insightful. HTC should be working on a fix.

Answer (score 1):

there is a dirty fix to it, create an empty contact that is only the name but no number, then merge the fb contact with the dummy contact. Should set it right, as i said it is a dirty fix but it works.